# List filenames up to a limit per each text file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

How can I create a number of text files, which include the filenames of the files in a specific directory, up to a maximum of 999 rows per text file?

I started from this:

```
find ./J0902-405/*.evt -maxdepth 1 -type f -fprintf files_xselect.list %f\\n
```

And it writes the filenames properly in the textfile.
But afterwords, I need to put the 999 rows limit, and after that limit, create another text file with the following 999 names, and so on, until all the *.evt files are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DopeGhoti's answer is the right approach, but let me flesh it out a bit, for those new to `split` (like me):

```
find ./J0902-405 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.evt' -type f -printf '%f\n' | \
  split -l 999 -d - files_xselect.list.
```

- `-name ...` with a *quoted* filename pattern lets *find* do the pathname expansion (as opposed to the shell - no point in letting both the shell and `find` do the work).
- `-printf '%f\n'` ensures that only *filenames* (no path components) are output, as in the OP.
- `-l 999` specifies the split size in lines; default is 1000.
- `-d` causes *numerical* suffixes to be used for the output files (`00`, `01`, ...) rather than the default letters (`aa`, `ab`, ...) [note: won't work on OSX]; default suffix length is 2; to control the number of digits/chars. in the suffix, use `-a {length}`.
- `-` causes `split` to read from stdin - in this case, the output from `find`.
- `files_xselect.list.` is the output-file prefix; thus, we get files `files_xselect.list.00`, `files_xselect.list.01`, ...

If you want **more control over the output filename** - e.g., to move the suffix data to a different part of the filename - you can use the `--filter` option (note: won't work on OS X), which accepts a shell command to which the output data for each file is piped, along with variable `$FILE` containing the name of the respective output filename; this gives you the chance to modify the output filename based on it:

For instance, to create output files named `files_xselect.00.list`, ... - i.e., to place the suffix data *before* the filename extension, you'd use:

```
... | split -l 999 -d --filter='> ${FILE}.list' - 'files_xselect.'
```

Answer (score 5):

`find ./J0902-405/*.evt -maxdepth 1 -type f | split -l999 -`

From the manual page:

```
NAME
   split - split a file into pieces

SYNOPSIS
   split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]

DESCRIPTION
   Output  fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 
   lines, and default PREFIX is `x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT is -, read standard 
   input.

   -l, --lines=NUMBER
          put NUMBER lines per output file
```

Comment: +1 Never heard of split before, learning something knew every day.

Comment: It's very much a truism in POSIX, that most of the time, there's already the tool for the job, for simple enough values of `$JOB`. (:

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./J0902-405/*.evt; do
  [[ $i > 999 ]] && i=0 && j=$((j+1))
  [[ -f $file ]] && i=$((i+1)) && echo "${file##*/}" >> "fileofnames$j.txt"
done
```